# How to sync local host with docker host?

Tags: django, docker, docker-compose

I have a hello world Django project and i want to dockerize it. My OS is windows 8.1 and I'm using docker toolbox. Using volumes I could persist data in docker container and what I want to do is to sync the code in docker container with the code in my local host in the directory where my project code is stored and so far I couldn't do it.

Here is my docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  web:
    build: .
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - myvol1:/code
    ports:
      - 8000:8000 

volumes: 
  myvol1:
```

and Dockerfile:

```
# Pull base image
FROM python:3.7

# Set environment variables
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

# Set work directory
WORKDIR /code

# Install dependencies
COPY requirement.txt /code/
RUN pip install -r requirement.txt

# Copy project
COPY . /code/
```

without using volumes I can run my code in the container but the data is not persisted.

I'd be grateful for your help.

Comment: Could you please add your Dockerfile? And the full docker-compose if anything is missing.

Comment: @ShimonCohen I have added both Dockerfile and docker-compose in the picture and they are complete

Comment: Seems like your following docker's official Django guide (https://docs.docker.com/compose/django/). Im not sure what the problem is. Sorry i couldn't help.

Comment: If you're trying to actively develop your service, a Python virtual environment might be an easier installation setup than Docker: you'll have an isolated set of local Python packages, but can still directly use your local source tree.

Comment: @DavidMAze Yes, that's true. But I just started learning Docker and I want to get acquainted with the work process of Docker.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  web:
    build: .
    command: python manage.py runserver 127.0.0.1:8000
    volumes:
      - myvol1:/code
    ports:
      - 8000:8000 

volumes: 
  myvol1:
```

I thought maybe changing to the localhost IP might help or the ports could also be changed following the format of

`<port-number-host> : <port-number-container>`

"your listening port : container's listening port"

The port might be busy, but these are things that I would troubleshoot and try.

My resources/references: Udemy Class from Bret Fisher